# PairRDD, multiline values to one line value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading a couple of files using *WholeTextFiles* but I would like to put all text lines into one line, I am using *reduce* or *reduceByKey* and maybe I am just doing wrong.

This is the PairRDD

```
Key          Text
|\test1.log  |line text1
|            |line text2
|            |line text3
|\test2.log  |line text1
|            |line text2
```

And I want to achive this:

```
Key          Text
|\test1.log  |line text1 line text2 line text3
|\test2.log  |line text1 line text2
```

I hope being clear.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I recently achive it with this:

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("C:\*.log").map({case (name, contents) =>
      (name, contents.replaceAll("[\r\n]", " ")
```